# how to perform Ctrl + Click in OATS(JAVA)?

Tags: java, automation, automated-tests

I'm working on OATS automation framework. In Oracle form I have to choose one line with pressing (Ctrl + Click) in manual testing, while automating I need to write a program to select a line with pressing (Ctrl + Click), how the thing will be done any Idea. There is no shortcut way to select the line in oracle forms. Basically Oracle forms are java applets. Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure about your use case but maybe `java.awt.Robot` could help:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Sample usage:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// press and hold CONTROL key
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);

// Left Click
robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK); 

// release CONTROL key
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Robot Class actually works as a user, you can use this to do any kind of keyboard activity.

Robot robot = new Robot(); 
// good to have delay of 5 sec.

```
robot.delay(5000); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.<KEY>); 
robot.keyRelease();
```

Answer (score 0):

OATS by default doesnot support keyboard operation or windows-based application automation.

For that you have to use external tools

1.AutoIT

2.RobotClass

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
 robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
 robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
 robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
```

For more tips on Oracle Application testing suite tool ie Openscript tool, you can find here

http://www.testinghive.com/category/oracle-application-testing-suite-tips/